# showing Div over its ::before and ::after?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying in my page to make `div` be shown over its `::before` and `::after` **CSS selectors**, so I'm working to get this result : [image: currently result]

but I'm getting this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D78ef/)
[image: what i want]

Here is my code :

### HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

## CSS

```
.box{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: #555;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.box::before{
    content: "";
    background: #A60000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.box::after{
    content: "";
    background: #02047A;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I know it looks like making `div` shown over its content because **Chrome** is showing me the **HTML source** like this :

[image]

but I hope there is a way to fix that ..

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: the only way to send child element to behind its parent is using ***negative*** z-index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your css to follow:

```
.box{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: #555;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
}
.box::before{
    content: "";
    background: #A60000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -150px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box::after{
    content: "";
    background: #02047A;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D78ef/5/)

All you have to do is to set `z-index` `:after` and `:before` to `-1` and remove from `.box` `z-index`.

Comment: In my case, z-index: -1 was causing the pseudo-element to disappear behind an ancestor's pseudo-element. I fixed it by giving my equivalent of the ".box" element a position (relative, in my case) and z-index: 0

Answer (score 3):

Add or replace the properties below (to make `:before` and `:after` elements display behind `.box` apply `z-index:-1` and use default `z-index` for `.box`) :

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
}
.box::before{
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.box::after{
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[image]

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D78ef/8/)

Comment: thank you for your help, but #Alek wrote a bit better explanation (remove from .box z-index) so :)